# Runtime error DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$DefaultProviderHolder for GraalVM native image

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

Im trying to build a native image for spring cloud gateway using GraalVM. I've managed to build a native image that can bootup but at the first http request I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$DefaultProviderHolder
        at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:239) ~[na:na]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.unixDefault(DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.java:107) ~[gatewayapplication.exe:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.platformDefault(DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.java:103) ~[gatewayapplication.exe:4.1.60.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder.<init>(DnsNameResolverBuilder.java:60) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.transport.NameResolverProvider.newNameResolverGroup(NameResolverProvider.java:405) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources.getOrCreateDefaultResolver(TcpResources.java:306) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.http.HttpResources.getOrCreateDefaultResolver(HttpResources.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfig.defaultAddressResolverGroup(HttpClientConfig.java:380) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.transport.ClientTransportConfig.resolverInternal(ClientTransportConfig.java:219) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfig.resolverInternal(HttpClientConfig.java:434) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.lambda$subscribe$0(HttpClientConnect.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:76) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryWhen.java:46) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57) ~[na:na]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:271) ~[na:na]
```

Adding this flag, didn't help

```
--initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$DefaultProviderHolder
```

And adding an entry to the reflect-config, didn't neither

```
{
  "name":"io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$DefaultProviderHolder"
}
```

The project can be found here: https://github.com/hanouard/demo-native-gateway

Do you have any idea what's causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what Im trying to achieve is not yet supported by Spring Native:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#support-spring-cloud

I guess they updated their documentation since, I've seen in 0.9.1 support for spring cloud gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I reached the same issue after upgrade Spring Boot from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4 and my error looks like this:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfig does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract io.netty.resolver.AddressResolverGroup defaultAddressResolverGroup()' of abstract class reactor.netty.transport.ClientTransportConfig.
    at reactor.netty.transport.ClientTransportConfig.resolverInternal(ClientTransportConfig.java:219)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfig.resolverInternal(HttpClientConfig.java:420)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.lambda$subscribe$0(HttpClientConnect.java:262)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(FluxRetryWhen.java:76)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(MonoRetryWhen.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:269)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8227)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:255)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:255)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:255)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:281)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:860)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:281)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:860)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilterWhen$MonoFilterWhenMain.onNext(MonoFilterWhen.java:149)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilterWhen$MonoFilterWhenMain.onSubscribe(MonoFilterWhen.java:112)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:448)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:250)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize$DematerializeSubscriber.onNext(FluxDematerialize.java:98)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize$DematerializeSubscriber.onNext(FluxDematerialize.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:270)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:228)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize$DematerializeSubscriber.request(FluxDematerialize.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:235)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDematerialize$DematerializeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxDematerialize.java:77)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:62)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:448)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:218)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:255)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4265)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4057)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.HttpHandlerConnector.lambda$doConnect$2(HttpHandlerConnector.java:98)
    at org.springframework.mock.http.client.reactive.MockClientHttpRequest.lambda$null$2(MockClientHttpRequest.java:125)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable$ConcatIterableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatIterable.java:147)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable.subscribe(FluxConcatIterable.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4265)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4057)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.HttpHandlerConnector.doConnect(HttpHandlerConnector.java:112)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.HttpHandlerConnector.lambda$connect$0(HttpHandlerConnector.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(MonoSubscribeOn.java:126)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I was able to fix it by adding the following bean:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.HttpClientCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import io.netty.resolver.DefaultAddressResolverGroup;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

@Configuration
public class HttpClientResolverFixConfig {

    @Bean
    public HttpClientCustomizer httpClientResolverCustomizer() {
        return new HttpClientCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public HttpClient customize(HttpClient httpClient) {
                return httpClient.resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Take a look here for more details: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1431

Comment: the error you faced has nothing to do with GraalVM and native image.